# stored function returnin NULL instead than DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created the following sfunction

```
CREATE  FUNCTION sf_GetTrainingDate (@ID_ITEM int,@EMPLOYEE VARCHAR)
RETURNS DATETIME AS

BEGIN
 --(1)
 DECLARE @RESULT DATETIME
 DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
 DECLARE @REPEAT_INTERVAL INT 
 SET @DATE = (/*subquery returning a date in datetime format*/)
 SET @REPEAT_INTERVAL = (/*subquery returning a datetime */)
  WHILE @DATE <= getdate()
  BEGIN
  SET @DATE=dateadd(month,@REPEAT_INTERVAL,@DATE)
  IF @DATE > GETDATE()
  BREAK
  ELSE
  CONTINUE
  END
 SET @RESULT = @DATE     
 RETURN @RESULT
 --(2)
END
```

The code works correctly, I mean if I run only the part from (1) to (2) using some PRINT commands to read the value of @DATE all is fine, but as i use the stored function it returns NULL instead of a date.

Could you give me an hand?

Comment: I don't get why you think that the `PRINT` is the indicator of the function working correctly. What happens when you do something like this: `SELECT sf_GetTrainingDate(SomeId,SomeEmployee)`?, does it return a correct value?

Comment: The only time this should return null, is if either *@DATE* is NULL or *@REPEAT_INTERVAL* is null

Comment: @Lamak in that case it returns NULL

Comment: @user193655 Then your function isn't working correctly, it doesn't matter if it is inside your stored procedure or not. You should assign the initial values for `@DATE` and `@REPEAT_INTERVAL` using `SELECT`, not `SET`: `SELECT @DATE = (/*subquery returning a date in datetime format*/)`

Comment: I'd suggest adding `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate()` and using `@Now` in the loop.  You are chasing a moving target and will have a heck of a time finding the bug when running this around midnight (assuming the time is 00:00:00).

Comment: I tried to put 'SET @DATE=getdate()` instead of `SET @DATE=dateadd(month,@REPEAT_INTERVAL,@DATE)` to force getdate() as result, but I have NULL anyway, so is suspect something is not ok in this overall syntax (this begin end approach).

Comment: I took this function as presented here and created it - if either `@DATE` or `@REPEAT_INTERVAL` is NULL, then the function returns NULL. I note that in the comments you say that `@REPEAT_INTERVAL` is set by a subquery that returns a `DATETIME` - however `DATEADD` does not accept a `DATETIME` as its second parameter, it must be an integer. Is it possible that your subqueries for either `@DATE` and/or `@REPEAT_INTERVAL` are failing and returning NULL?